# Query column twice with union all

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to do a union all to produce data for reporting, below is what I have so far, it shows all the data I want but I cannot get the data in the same rows, it produces the two rows at a minimum with null in the corresponding column. I am hoping that there is a way so that I can get the data in the same row?

```
select account, campaign, sale, date
from
(
SELECT CHACCOUNTNO as account, CONTSUPREF as campaign,null as sale, ONDATE as date
FROM            dbo.MKTDW
WHERE        (RESULTCODE = 'D01') and CONTACT IN ('Campaign ID')
group by CHACCOUNTNO, CONTSUPREF, ONDATE

UNION ALL

SELECT CHACCOUNTNO as account, null as campaign, CONTSUPREF as sale, ONDATE as date
FROM            dbo.MKTDW
WHERE        (RESULTCODE = 'D01') and CONTACT IN ('Order')
group by CHACCOUNTNO, CONTSUPREF, ONDATE
)account
group by account,campaign,sale,date
order by account
```

**Current Result:**

```
account                 campaign   sale      date                    
A2043056003(2IJUMI M    NULL       N177618   2014-07-21 00:00:00.000
A2043056003(2IJUMI M    LT08704    NULL      2014-07-21 00:00:00.000
```

**Expected result:**

A2043056003(2IJUMI M) LT08704 N177618 2014-07-21 00:00:00.000

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: account   LT08704(campaign)    N177618(sale)   2014-07-21 00:00:00.000 (date)   all in the same row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer will be straightforward. If you want something shown in horizontal way, use JOINs instead of SET operators. The code is listed below, tested, works perfect in SSMS. :)

```
--create table structure
create table dbo.MKTDW 
(   CHACCOUNTNO varchar(100), 
    CONTSUPREF varchar(10), 
    RESULTCODE varchar(10), 
    CONTACT varchar(50), 
    ONDATE datetime)
go

--insert sample data
insert dbo.MKTDW 
select 'A2043056003(2IJUMI M)', 'N177618', 'D01', 'Order', '2014-07-21 00:00:00.000'
union all
select 'A2043056003(2IJUMI M)', 'LT08704', 'D01', 'Campaign ID', '2014-07-21 00:00:00.000'
union all
select 'B2043056003(2IJUMI M)', 'M000000', 'D01', 'Order', '2014-07-21 00:00:00.000'
union all
select 'B2043056003(2IJUMI M)', 'X111111', 'D01', 'Campaign ID', '2014-07-21 00:00:00.000'


--below is the solution
select  a.CHACCOUNTNO as account, 
        a.CONTSUPREF as campaign, 
        b.CONTSUPREF as sale, 
        a.ondate as date        
from dbo.MKTDW as a
join dbo.MKTDW as b
on a.CHACCOUNTNO = b.CHACCOUNTNO
where   a.CONTACT = 'campaign id' 
        and b.CONTACT = 'order' 
        and a.RESULTCODE = 'D01' 
        and b.RESULTCODE = 'D01'
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: That is awesome, thanks Henry! the only problem I can see is it produces duplicate lines (one for each time the accountno occurrs)

Comment: can you please clarify it? I dont see any possibilities you can get some dups. Are there any sample data you can write here?

Comment: sorry when I try and paste sample data it is just a jumbled mess

Comment: All good, I added a distinct to acccount and that seems to work well, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of union all and specifying null ..

```
SELECT CHACCOUNTNO as account, CONTSUPREF as campaign,CONTSUPREF as sale, ONDATE as date
FROM            dbo.MKTDW
WHERE        (RESULTCODE = 'D01') and CONTACT IN ('Campaign ID','order')
group by CHACCOUNTNO, CONTSUPREF, ONDATE
```

When any of the above group by columns have null,Null will be treated as seperate group

Comment: Thanks but this query leaves the 'sale' column as null for every row

Comment: Still no good, this query replicates the values for both 'campaign' and 'sale', the campaign field is for values from the table where another field (contact) is 'campaign id', whilst the 'sale' value is where the 'contact' field is 'order'

To clarify, this select is for a supplementary table that has many different entries for different purposes in our crm (user defined fields). The 'contact' field determines what type of entry each row is, the 'accountno' field is the unique identifier that relates the rows. I want to bring the different rows for each accountno together into a single row